How to setup multiple packeges for AppExhange listing?
We have a appexchange listing built on 2gp, we are planning to release a new feature as an upgrade to the existing package. But we wish to charge additional amount for it.

Is it possible to have that new feature as seperate child package?

If yes any documents related to ISV, can't find a way in partners page?

Any other best way for my approach like api usage based restrictions or component based restrictions?



Is it possible to have that new feature as seperate child package?

Yes. You'll make the base package a dependency for the child package. The dependency itself is created in the managed package, not on the partner portal or anywhere else.

Any other best way for my approach like api usage based restrictions or component based restrictions?

You can use the FeatureManagement class to check if there are specific entitlements that you configure in the LMO. This can be easier by keeping all of your logic in a single package. However, if you want the extension as a separate listing, you'll need a separate package.
Note that the separate package will need its own security review. You'll need to plan accordingly.
